# what is the different between const char *m = "mnopqr" and const char m = "mnopqr", and why the latter causes segment error

Tags: c, pointers

here is the code from CSAPP

```
#include <stdio.h>
    
typedef unsigned char *byte_pointer;
    
void show_bytes(byte_pointer start, size_t len){
    
    int i;
        
    for (i=0; i<len; i++)
        printf(" %.2x", start[i]); 
    
    printf("\n");
}

void main(){
    
    // only one enabled at a time for testing
    const char *m = "mnoqpr"; /* works fine */
    const char m = "mnoqpr"; /* Segmentation fault */

    show_bytes((byte_pointer) m, strlen(m));
    
    int a = 1;
}
```

can some one please explain why the `const char *m = "mnoqpr"` works fine but `const char m = "mnoqpr"` causes fault, as the `*m` should be the pointer right? and `*m` has not defined previously, nothing can put into `*m`, but why it works here?

Comment: The second one shouldn't even compile - does it?

Comment: This code won't compile as you have two definitions for `m` in the same scope.

Comment: @dbush I think he's showing two alternative declarations, not using both at the same time.

Comment: @Barmar is right, but if you comment out the `char *` version the code compiles with a howl of warnings that the OP really ought to be asking about rather than why the code segfaults.  I admit to being surprised that the code compiles.

Comment: @SteveFriedl C allows you to convert between integers and pointers, although the results are implementation-dependent. If you enable full warnings I'm sure it will howl about assigning to a smaller size.

Comment: I don't remember ever seeing a pointer convertible to a char, but I guess it follows all the rules.   Just surprised me, and I've been doing C a long time.  And even without any compiler flags asking for warnings, `gcc` (v8.3.1 at least) squeals like a stuck pig about all of the bad stuff.

Comment: thanks for helping me to add more comment, that is right, only one work, not both run at the same time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`const char m` declares `m` to be a single character.

The initializer `"mnopq"` is a string literal. When used to initialize a variable other than a `char` array, it's converted to the address of its first character.

So this is initializing the character `m` to contain an address. But `char` only contains 1 byte, while addresses are likely 4 or 8 bytes. So most of the bytes of the address are being discarded when initializing `m`.

When you then cast this to `byte_pointer`, this 1-byte address is expanded 4 or 8 bytes. This will be very low-numbered addresses, which is probably reserved by the operating system. So you get a segmentation violation.

Comment: great, explanation. :)

Comment: hi, thanks for answering, so will const char *m also declares *m to be a single character? why it won't cause segmentation fault?

Comment: It declares it as a pointer. It can point to a single character or an element of of an array of characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you simplify it as much as possible, then the compiler can help.  When I compile and run this with `gcc test.c && ./a.out`...

```
#include <stdio.h>

void
main(void)
{
    //const char *m = "mnoqpr"; /* works fine */
    const char m = "mnoqpr"; /* Segmentation fault */
    printf("%s", m);
}
```

I get these warnings in the compilation before the crash:

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:7:20: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     const char m = "mnoqpr"; /* Segmentation fault */
                    ^~~~~~~~
test.c:8:14: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("%s", m);
             ~^
             %d
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

In human terms, the type of "mnopqr" is a pointer to a constant array of characters, but the type of m is a single 8 bit integer (char).  In the case you have that runs ok, you have two things that are the same type.

Comment: Oops!  Too slow!  =)

Comment: sorry, I actually was showing a comparison between const char m and const char *m, the previous one cause segmentation fault, I wonder why the latter won't cause anything wrong?